# How to check if data mobile is ready to send information in Android?

Tags: android

I want to reduce the impact on connection time for "mobile data" (because my provider charges this) I'm doing something like this:

```
public void sendEmail(Context context) {
    try {
        NetHelper.setMobileDataEnabled(context, true);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }

    // sending email in background (this works perfectly)

    try {
        NetHelper.setMobileDataEnabled(context, false);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My method for setMobileDataEnabled is as follow:

```
public static void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    final Field connectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    connectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object connectivityManager = connectivityManagerField.get(conman);
    final Class connectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(connectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = connectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(connectivityManager, enabled);
}
```

The problem seems to be that the email does not have enough time to be sent. I suspect this because when "mobile data" is on before to call
sendEmail it works ok. So, my question is: how can i know if "mobile data" is ready to send information and close it when transaction has done ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as a application is concerned, it should only check if a network is connected.

One could do this:

```
ConnectivityManager connMngr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ntwrkInfo = connMngr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ntwrkInfo != null && ntwrkInfo.isConnected()) {
        // do the internets stuffs.
    } else {
        // fail gracefully, or ask for network to the user.
    }
```

Comment: I know it's connected, but I turn off too quick i guess.

Comment: Where are you closing the connection? What response do you get from the server? If you are using some HTTP protocol, then receiving a 200 status code is enough. Once you do, then close the connection.

Comment: I close data connection in the code above with NetHelper.setMobileDataEnabled(context, false); I'm using javamail to send mails . nothing to do with http requests

Comment: What API and device are you executing this code? `setMobileDataEnabled` is a private method, depending on the device, it might not exist (and throw a NPE). If it exists but its not fully functional, then you might be corrupting some part of your code. Since you have not posted a Logcat, I suppose your code works on an emulated device, but does nothing in a real one. Finally, post your permissions, do you have `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, .CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, INTERNET, READ_PHONE_STATE`?